# Send long uri to rest service with query part

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, webrequest

this is my scenario:
I have a Rest service that has a string parameter in query part that will be deserialized as a complex object that contains a byte[]:

```
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "json?doc={doc}")]
        string UploadDocument(string doc);
```

This is my UploadDocument inheritation:

```
public string UploadDocument(string doc) 
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(doc))
        return "ko";
    JavaScriptSerializer jscript = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    Document inputDocument = jscript.Deserialize<Document>(doc);
    return "ok";
}
```

I need to call it from a client in which I read the content of a file and I put this one in parameter:

```
JavaScriptSerializer jscript = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            Document newComp = jscript.Deserialize<Document>(test);
            newComp.Content = File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\Test\PdfParse\test.pdf");
            newComp.filename = "test.pdf";

            test = jscript.Serialize(newComp);
            ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] data = encoder.GetBytes(test);
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/DocumentUpload/DocumentUpload.svc/json?doc=");
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;

            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
            WebResponse wr = request.GetResponse();

            using (StreamReader sw = new StreamReader(wr.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                test = (sw.ReadToEnd());

            }
```

**Question**
If I add "test" content in WebRequest.Create the url is too long, but writing it to requestStream rest service return to me that "doc" is always empty.
In which way can I pass the parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You can consume in your method a multipart_form_data media type.
In this case you can pass streams to your code directly.

I think this link wuill help you:
http://www.briangrinstead.com/blog/multipart-form-post-in-c

Good luck